# Preferences not getting updated until the app is restarted

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am taking IP ,Port and Device Name settings from User and using them in initializing an object. However when i am putting settings ,those settings are not getting updated in app ,until i restart the app.

Here is my Settings File-

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);

        SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
        EditTextPreference editTextPrefLAN = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("prefABCLan");
        editTextPrefLAN
                .setSummary(sp.getString("prefABCLan", "Set your LAN IP"));





        EditTextPreference editTextPrefPort = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("prefABCPort");
        editTextPrefPort
                .setSummary(sp.getString("prefABCPort", "Set your port"));
        EditTextPreference editTextPrefDeviceName = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("prefABCDeviceName");
        editTextPrefDeviceName
                .setSummary(sp.getString("prefABCDeviceName", "Set your device name"));

        /*EditTextPreference editTextPrefScopeIP = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("prefScopeIP");
        editTextPrefScopeIP
                .setSummary(sp.getString("prefScopeIP", "Set your Scope IP"));
        EditTextPreference editTextPrefScopeLogin = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("prefScopeLogin");

*/


    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                          String key) {
        Preference pref = findPreference(key);
        if (pref instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) pref;
            pref.setSummary(etp.getText());
        }
    }
```

Is there anything i need to do in my code?

Comment: First, how are you determining that "those settings are not getting updated in app"? Second, do you have any `android:process` attributes in your manifest?

Comment: @CommonsWare Initially i am inputting wrong IP in my app. Then i am changing to correct IP and sending data from another activity inside app which uses these prefs. But the Activity is still using Old Prefs instead of New Prefs.  And again if i restart my app , the data is sent using new settings.

Comment: @CommonsWare why do i need process entry in manifest?

Comment: "But the Activity is still using Old Prefs instead of New Prefs" -- and what did you do to load the new preferences values into the activity? "why do i need process entry in manifest?" -- you specifically **do not** need `android:process` in your manifest. If you had them, though, that might explain part of your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare IDK , <<But the Activity is still using Old Prefs instead of New Prefs" -- and what did you do to load the new preferences values into the activity? >>i am trying to research into what i should do to load new values into the app. That was my question.

Answer (score 1):

When the user modifies preferences in a `PreferenceActivity`, you still need to do something elsewhere in your app to use those preferences. This is particularly true if you read the preferences earlier, and now need the changed values.

One approach is just to reload the preferences, by putting your preference-reading logic in a lifecycle method like `onResume()` that will be called *both* when the activity/fragment is created *and* when it returns to the screen after the user visited the `PreferenceActivity`.

Another approach is to use the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the other components, just as you are using it here. Activities (or fragments or whatever) that care about preference changes would register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and watch for relevant changes.